# UICollectionView reload data Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a problem with data reloading using `UICollectionView`. I have this array on the `viewDidLoad` to fill the `UICollectionView.`

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:@"1"];
[array addObject:@"2"];
[array addObject:@"3"];
[array addObject:@"4"];
[array addObject:@"5"];
[array addObject:@"6"];
```

and the method:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    //cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    myCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 100, 20)];
    [titleLabel setText:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell addSubview:titleLabel];

    return cell;
}
```

I tap the `UIButton` and data is reloaded:

```
[myCollectionView reloadData];
```

Here how the data looks like before and after the reload:
[image: Before]

[image: After]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You add a new label each time you tap the reload button. You should add the label once and change the label text according.

Here a simple example.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"
                                                                               forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setMyTextLabel:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

where `MyCell` will contains a `UILabel` and a property to modify its text.

I really suggest to take a look at [Fun with UICollectionView](https://github.com/subdigital/nsscreencast/tree/master/046-fun-with-uicollectionview) code by **@Ben Scheirman**.

Hope that helps.

P.S. Rename `myCell` to `MyCell`. A class should start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Please tell me what is "MyCell", is it a class

Comment: Any better way? you have to create custom cell to avoid cache data in uicollectionview

Answer (score 1):

You are adding your label when you tap reload button. In that case you are adding label again and again...

So there are three solutions:

- Make your cell reusable
- Remove your cell from superview in reload method.
- You can check if label's `text` length is not equal to zero. In that case no need to add that label and change text.

Comment: But how to remove the Cell from the superview on the reload?

Answer (score 1):

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
       UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

  //  ********* Changed *******

        for (UIView *v in [cell.contentView subviews])
        [v removeFromSuperview];

 // ********** Changed **********
            if ([self.collectionviewFlow.indexPathsForVisibleItems containsObject:indexPath]) {
            NSString *img_name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_thumb%d.png",self.VaritiesName,(int)indexPath.row+1];
            imageVw=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: img_name]];
            imageVw.frame=CGRectMake(10,10,100,100);
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imageVw];
            }
       });
     cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
     return cell;
}
```

Comment: @pradhyuman sinh: Hi, I am also facing a same problem with 100 cells.I tried your solution but it is not working for me for iOS 8. Please tell me the solution to stop overlapping off cells issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is quit late, but here is my solution.

if you used custom collectionviewcell 
try to use 'func prepareForReuse()'