# UICollectionView Cells not clearing on reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a similar problem to these ones but can't seem to fix my problem..

1. [UICollectionView reload data Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16517844/1042240)
2. [ios UICollectionView cells not refreshing after scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22137536/1042240)
3. [UILabel overloading in UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753707/uilabel-overloading-in-uicollectionview)

I have a `CollectionView` with custom `UIViews` in the `cell`, On reloadData its re-adding the custom `UIViews` and not removing the ones already being shown. This is my cellForItemAtIndexPath…

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UICollectionViewCell *collectionViewCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"LiveTileCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDictionary *cellDataDictionary = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:collectionViewCell.contentView.frame];
customView.tag = 1002;


LiveTileView *liveTile = [[LiveTileView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, collectionViewCell.frame.size.width, collectionViewCell.frame.size.height)];
liveTile.tag = 1001;

[liveTile initialize:[cellDataDictionary valueForKey:@"backgroundColor"] titleFont:[cellDataDictionary valueForKey:@"titleFont"] titleText:[cellDataDictionary valueForKey:@"titleText"] titleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] titleImage:[cellDataDictionary valueForKey:@"titleImage"] badge:[[cellDataDictionary valueForKey:@"badge"] intValue] detailViewImage:[cellDataDictionary valueForKey:@"detailViewImage"] compactView:nil isLiveTile:[[cellDataDictionary valueForKey:@"isLiveTile"] boolValue] animationTime:[[cellDataDictionary valueForKey:@"animationTime"] floatValue] elementIndex:indexPath.item];

[customView addSubview:liveTile];
[collectionViewCell addSubview:customView];

return collectionViewCell;
}
```

Any help would be great.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UICollectionViewCell *collectionViewCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"LiveTileCell" forIndexPath:indexPath]; 


//    for(UIView *view in collectionViewCell.contentView.subviews)

 for(UIView *view in collectionViewCell.subviews)
 {
    for(UIView *subView in view.subviews)
    {

        [subView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
// write your code here
```

Comment: Why so? It is removing your existing view and then add your new custom view.

Comment: GOt it working.. changed `collectionViewCell.contentView.subviews` to `collectionViewCell.subviews` and its working great now :) THank you